# How could I change the header of several pages in Dreamweaver automatically?

Tags: html, web, dreamweaver

I would like to ask how I could modify the header section (the metatag, the title, the import information of CSS file) in several files automatically?

Of course I would do this by hand but that would take quite a long time to complete.

The software I used is Dreamweaver

Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use find and replace (ctrl + f), you can select it to run across a whole folder of files.